# Deploy a visual webpart developed with VS2010 to Sharepoint 2007

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I developed a simple webpart using the **Visual Webpart** template in Visual studio 2010 and has been testing it within Sharepoint 2010.

I want to know if this webpart could be deployed to Sharepoint 2007 from the .cab generated by VS2010, and if so, how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, that isn't possible

Comment: Can you provide more information please? because basically, the Visual webpart is nothing than a standard webpart with a user control!

Comment: That's right, but the project references the assemblies for SharePoint 2010, not 2007. There is a way to deploy visual webparts to SharePoint 2007, but it involves removing these references and replacing them with references to the SharePoint 2007 assemblies. Take a look at this article for more information: http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2010/07/16/visual-web-parts-in-moss-2007.aspx